# Adding a random color parameter to a function

Tags: javascript

Exactly as the title says, I'm trying to add a random color parameter (as a 4th parameter) to a pre-existing function. I have tried many things but nothing has been working.

That is what I'm working with. I know, it's not efficient but I'm a beginner. It's a smiley face. I need to add a random color parameter so that only the first 'fillStyle' gets changed but the rest of the colors remain the same. How can I achieve this?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv"),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  width = 500,
  height = 500;

function pintaSmiley(cX, cY, s) {
  "use strict";
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "yellow";
  context.arc(cX, cY, 100 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.moveTo(55, 50);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.arc(cX - 35 * s, cY - 38 * s, 16 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.moveTo(103, 49);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.arc(cX + 35 * s, cY - 38 * s, 16 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.moveTo(55, 50);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.arc(cX - 32 * s, cY - 43 * s, 9 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.moveTo(103, 49);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.arc(cX + 38 * s, cY - 43 * s, 9 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.moveTo(105, 75);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
  context.arc(cX, cY + 10 * s, 60 * s, 0, Math.PI, false);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
}

for (i = 0; i < 94; i = i + 1) {
  centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
  centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
  size = 15;
  size = size / 100;
  pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size);
}

pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size * 14);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.1);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.2);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.3);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.4);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.5);
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv"><</canvas>
```

Comment: whats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean

```
context.fillStyle = ["yellow","red","green"][Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
```

or perhaps

```
var bgArr = ["yellow","red","green"];
var rndBg = bgArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgArr.length)];
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size, rndBg);
```

using

```
function pintaSmiley(cX, cY, s, bg) {
  "use strict";
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = bg;
```

Here is the first:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv"),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  width = 500,
  height = 500;

function pintaSmiley(cX, cY, s) {
  "use strict";
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = ["yellow","red","green"][Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
  context.arc(cX, cY, 100 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.moveTo(55, 50);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.arc(cX - 35 * s, cY - 38 * s, 16 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.moveTo(103, 49);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.arc(cX + 35 * s, cY - 38 * s, 16 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.moveTo(55, 50);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.arc(cX - 32 * s, cY - 43 * s, 9 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.moveTo(103, 49);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.arc(cX + 38 * s, cY - 43 * s, 9 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.moveTo(105, 75);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
  context.arc(cX, cY + 10 * s, 60 * s, 0, Math.PI, false);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
}

for (i = 0; i < 94; i = i + 1) {
  centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
  centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
  size = 15;
  size = size / 100;
  pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size);
}

pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size * 14);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.1);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.2);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.3);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.4);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.5);
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv"><</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use the [HSL Color](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp) mode and use it with a random hue value.

```
context.fillStyle = "hsl("+Math.round(Math.random()*360)+",100%,50%)";
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv"),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  width = 500,
  height = 500;

function pintaSmiley(cX, cY, s, hue) {
  "use strict";
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "hsl("+hue+",100%,50%)";
  context.arc(cX, cY, 100 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.moveTo(55, 50);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.arc(cX - 35 * s, cY - 38 * s, 16 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.moveTo(103, 49);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.arc(cX + 35 * s, cY - 38 * s, 16 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.moveTo(55, 50);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.arc(cX - 32 * s, cY - 43 * s, 9 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.moveTo(103, 49);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.arc(cX + 38 * s, cY - 43 * s, 9 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.moveTo(105, 75);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
  context.arc(cX, cY + 10 * s, 60 * s, 0, Math.PI, false);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
}

for (i = 0; i < 94; i = i + 1) {
  centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
  centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
  size = 15;
  size = size / 100;
  pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size, Math.round(Math.random()*360));
}

pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size * 14, Math.round(Math.random()*360));
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.1, Math.round(Math.random()*360));
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.2, Math.round(Math.random()*360));
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.3, Math.round(Math.random()*360));
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.4, Math.round(Math.random()*360));
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.5, Math.round(Math.random()*360));
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv"><</canvas>
```

Comment: That's nice too :)

Comment: That's absolutely beautiful but what I need is a fourth parameter for the "pintaSmiley" function, something like "pintaSmiley(cX, cY, s, color)" :)

Comment: @DogukanTUNA you can make the hue as a parameter. I updated the snippet, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function for generate random color.

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv"),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  width = 500,
  height = 500;

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function pintaSmiley(cX, cY, s) {
  "use strict";
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
  context.arc(cX, cY, 100 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.moveTo(55, 50);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.arc(cX - 35 * s, cY - 38 * s, 16 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.moveTo(103, 49);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.arc(cX + 35 * s, cY - 38 * s, 16 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.moveTo(55, 50);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.arc(cX - 32 * s, cY - 43 * s, 9 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.moveTo(103, 49);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.arc(cX + 38 * s, cY - 43 * s, 9 * s, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.moveTo(105, 75);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
  context.arc(cX, cY + 10 * s, 60 * s, 0, Math.PI, false);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
}

for (i = 0; i < 94; i = i + 1) {
  centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
  centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
  size = 15;
  size = size / 100;
  pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size);
}

pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size * 14);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.1);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.2);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.3);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.4);
centerX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
centerY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
pintaSmiley(centerX, centerY, size + 0.5);
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv"><</canvas>
```

Comment: Funny how subdued your colors are compared to the HSL one

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks so much, but what I need is a fourth parameter for the "pintaSmiley" function :)